# Normalize discrete data on a scale from 0 to 10

Tags: normality-assumption, likert, discrete-data

I know this subject must have been treated already but I can't figure out how to deal with my problem on an example different from my situation : I measured pain on different location with a Likert scale from 0 to 10 (the scale is discrete, every number is separate by 1 point). That is, by doing test for normality distribution, the results show that scores are not normaly distributed (with Shapiro-Wilk test and Kolmogorov-Smirnov test). I think that the problem is that during pre intervention testing, the values appears frequently to be 0.
[image]

We need to compare two time of measure (pre and post intervention) to see group, time and group*time interaction effect but without normalize data I can't figure out how to do this.

I heard about ordered logistic regression model but I don't understand the concept...  How can I deal with this ?

Comment: Please, describe more clearly your data, your model, and what you finally want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are two groups of 28 data (n=56 in total) of pain collected by a scale from 0 to 10 (scores can only be whole numbers). For both groups, the data were collected in two measurement times (pre and post). So there are 2 times 56 data on 2 groups.
We wanted to use a general linear model with repeated measures ANOVA to compare the pre and post values between the groups and to see if one group showed a different evolution than the other group. 
We don't know how to compare these two groups without a general linear model. What do you think ?